# Asynchronous Excel Export in Angular KendoUI exports empty collection

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying to get an asynchronous excel export working in one of our grids but I consistently get an **empty xsls** file with **only the collection headers**.

Data is **properly being rendered in the grid**, with filtering and pagination.

I've tried following the docs over here without success, here's my implementation:

Relevant parts in my `component.ts`:

```
@Input() collection$: Observable<User[]>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.allData = this.allData.bind(this);
}

allData(): Observable<GridDataResult> {
  return this.collection$.pipe(
    map(users => ({ data: users, total: users.length }))
  );
}
```

First thing I tried was to directly return `this.collection$;` but the **behavior was the same**: empty collection inside the excel file thus I tried returning an `Observable<GridDataResult>` instead with no success either.

Relevant parts in my `component.html`:

```
<kendo-grid
  [kendoGridBinding]="collection$ | async"
  pageSize="10"
  [pageable]="true"
  [filterable]="true"
>
  <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
    <button type="button" kendoGridExcelCommand icon="file-excel">
      Export to Excel
    </button>
  </ng-template>

  <!-- columns -->

  <kendo-pager-prev-buttons></kendo-pager-prev-buttons>
  <kendo-pager-info></kendo-pager-info>
  <kendo-pager-next-buttons></kendo-pager-next-buttons>
  <kendo-pager-page-sizes [pageSizes]="[5, 10, 40]"></kendo-pager-page-sizes>
  <kendo-grid-excel
    fileName="Users.xlsx"
    [fetchData]="allData"
  ></kendo-grid-excel>
</kendo-grid>
```

Can anyone shed some light on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you populating `collection$` and `users$`?

Comment: @codingbadger forget about `users$`, that should be `collection$` (will edit now). `collection$` is the observable returned from the service, passed into the grid component from its parent container component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is because of the `rxjs` version:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/1962

Dropping `rxjs` and `rxjs-compat` to `6.2.2` fixed the issue.

**UPDATE**

Bumping to `6.4.0` also fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks for adding your own answer, I actually ran in to exactly the same issue today. Bumping both `rxjs` and `rxjs-compat` to `6.4.0` also fixes this issue

Comment: You're right, will add it now to the answer as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you add the package `@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export` and amend your `allData()` function to:

```
public allData(): ExcelExportData {
   const result: ExcelExportData = {
       data: this.collection$.pipe(
      map(users => ({ data: users, total: users.length })).data
   };
   return result;
}
```

That should work

Comment: This throws various TS compiler errors. Some typecasting can fix the errors but the issue still persists, apparently the problem resides with the rxjs version. Thank you for the help anyway, appreciate it.